# ASP.Net Core React spa integration test

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, integration-testing, single-page-application, xunit

Asp.Net Core integration testing seems pretty simple but for the life of me I can't test the starter app with my react dev server.  It runs fine from a browser so I assume node, npm and react are set up correctly but not under xUnit.  It fails with the following exception:

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to start 'npm'. To resolve this:.

[1] Ensure that 'npm' is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
    Current PATH enviroment variable is: {PATH}

Make sure the executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.

[2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The directory name is invalid
...

I assume this is because it can't find the content root of my spa so I have tried adding to my web host builder with no luck:

```
.UseSolutionRelativeContentRoot( "Solution Relative Path to My App" ) );
```

This is my test class:

```
public class SampleDataControllerTest
{

    private readonly TestServer server;
    private readonly HttpClient client;

    public SampleDataControllerTest()
    {
        server = new TestServer( WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseSolutionRelativeContentRoot( "Solution Relative Path to My App" ) );
            .UseEnvironment( "Development" );
        client = server.CreateClient();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task RootTest()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage page = await client.GetAsync( "/" );
        Assert.NotNull( page );
        Assert.Equal( HttpStatusCode.OK, page.StatusCode );
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick for me was setting the development environment variable to point to the directory where the `packages.json` file resides.

Below is an excerpt of the constructor of my xUnit integration test class.

Note that it first determines the solution directory (using `GetExecutingAssembly().Location`), and then points to the web source project folder. (In our environment, `Client.React` is a directory under the solution directory that contains the `packages.json` file).

Then, the directory is set using `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory`, followed by the test server being set up wit hthe `UseWebRoot`, again pointing to the  directory where the `packages.json` file resides.

`Startup` is the ASP.NET web startup class.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public IntegrationTest() : base()
    {
        var testAssemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        // Remove the "\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.1"
        var solutionPath = Directory.GetParent(testAssemblyPath.Substring(0, testAssemblyPath.LastIndexOf(@"\bin\", StringComparison.Ordinal))).FullName;
        var clientReactPath = Path.Join(solutionPath, "Client.React");

        // Important to ensure that npm loads and is pointing to correct directory
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(clientReactPath);

        var server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
            .UseWebRoot(clientReactPath)
            .UseStartup<Startup>());

        _client = server.CreateClient();

    }
```

Comment: Had this issue in my integration test project. This saved me.